# Vue - use axios in component or route view?

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, axios

For example I have site about cars. I have component called CarData that displays brand, model, photos etc about specific car. All of is stored on database, available by REST (laravel framework), for example under 
"/cars/5" that returns JSON with data for car with ID 5.

Now I want to use this component in two separate places, two routes - in page about this specific car model and in for ex. homepage where is showed latest model. There is always single car model on page, without listing multiple cars.

I think I can do this two ways:

A. On both pages I will put component and pass car ID as props:

```
<car-data :car-id:="5"></car-data>
```

Then in component I will get this car-id prop and make ajax request (by axios) to receive info about car ID 5 and display in this component.

B. On both pages I will make this ajax request (not in component, by in route view), and then pass to component already received data about car. Component will be used only for displaying content, not making any requests.

```
<car-data :car="car"></car-data>
```

Normally I would choose "A" option because repeating the same ajax requests doesn't feel right for me, but somewhere I found text like this 
"Components shouldn't be accessing axios directly.". So I don't know how to feel about this.

Maybe A and B is wrong, and I should make something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer option A since this way you get only the information you need, but if you need to display information about more than a car at the time I recommend you to get all the information first.

I hope this resource will help you a little bit more: https://codeburst.io/how-to-call-api-in-a-smart-way-2ca572c6fe86